# Set an angular "super global" variable

Tags: angular

I am using a service in order to set a token that my backend gives me when I submit a login endpoint from one of my components.. I am injecting my service at top level (in app.module.ts) in that way I am able to append a header with that token to every request my app makes using an Interceptor. The problem is that every time I reload the page on browser (for example with F5), the entire app is reloaded and is giivng me a new istance of the service I am Injecting on my app.module and with so I am loosing my token variable..

Is there a way to create a sort of "super global" variable that is still there even if I reload my angular app?

Comment: A cookie or local storage could be what you are looking for

Comment: ^ That's your answer.  There's no way to preserve information within the app after a reload, you have to use an external storage method.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery For example ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could use the localstorage for percisting. 
Then when your app loads, look into the localstorage to see if a token exist: `const token = storage.getItem("token");`

And when you receive a new token, you add it to the localstorage:

`storage.setItem("token", "jojio8JoloJ8joJOk7656r5");`